# Sending Static Confirmation Mail through Rails App using DEVISE + Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am a newbie to sending mails through rails. I have implemented `devise` in my project and now I want to send a confirmation email and/or a password-reset email. What changes do I need to make in Devise?? No errors are displayed, but still I don't receive any email.

I have done searching a lots and also refer many Stackoverflow's Answers but still not getting the working solution. I know there is some configuration mistake but can't point out.

Here are some codes If you need more then please comment I will update.

config/**environment.rb**

```
# Load the Rails application.
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!

ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
```

config/environments/**development.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true  # put this line manually
  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
      :port                 => 587,
      :domain               => 'localhost:3000',
      :user_name            => 'gagangami@gmail.com',
      :password             => 'testpass',
      :authentication       => 'plain',
      :enable_starttls_auto => true  }
end
```

config/initializers/**devise.rb**

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.mailer_sender = 'gagangami@gmail.com'
  config.mailer = 'Devise::Mailer'
  require 'devise/orm/active_record'
  config.authentication_keys = [ :login ]
  config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email ]
  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :email ]
  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]
  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10
  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10
  config.reconfirmable = true
  config.confirmation_keys = [ :login ]
  config.password_length = 8..128
  config.reset_password_keys = [ :login ]
  config.reset_password_within = 6.hours
  config.sign_out_via = :delete
end
```

app/mailer/**admin_mailer.rb**

```
class AdminMailer < Devise::Mailer
  default from: "gagangami@gmail.com"

end
```

I appreciate for your relevant answer. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are there any errors in your console or log files?  People often have troubles authenticating with Gmail...  Usually the reason is in a log somewhere.

Comment: I am not getting any error but mail is not sent to user.